# Is there “proper” filter in topology/set theory?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Is there a concept of proper filter?  Let F be a filter on topological space X.  Can we claim the filter not containing whole space X is still filter?  Or is every filter must include underlying set or space?

Comment: Every filter on $X$ contains $X$ as an element. What's excluded is the whole power set or, which is equivalent, that a filter contains $\emptyset$ as an element. The power set could be named an improper filter, but usually the definition of filter just excludes it.

Comment: If we allow filter to contain only finite set of a point, can that exclude the whole set?

Comment: Given any family $\mathfrak{P}\subseteq 2^X$ of nonempty subsets of $X$ which is closed under taking finite intersections you can define a $\mathfrak{P}$-filter in the obvious way. It is up to you whether this is interesting or not. Example: $X$ is a topological space and $\mathfrak{P}$ = open/closed/clopen/zero/cozero sets. Application: a space $X$ is compact if and only if each closed-set ultrafilter on it converges. I don't see why you can't take $\mathfrak{P}=2^X\setminus\{X\}$ if you like.

Comment: @Tyrone the closedness of the sets is not necessary in the compactness characterisation and is usually omitted.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma more interesting example: $X$ is sober if and only if the completely prime open set filters on it are exactly the neighbourhood filters.

Comment: @Tyrone Or a Hausdorff $X$ is H-closed iff every open ultrafilter has an adherent point. (IIRC).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $X$ is Hausdorff and... ;)

Comment: Indeed, but without the Hausdorff is also called a special name .. @Tyrone

Answer (score 3):

A *filter* $F$ on a set $X$ (it doesn't matter if $X$ has additional structure) is a nonempty subset of $P(X)$ (the power set of $X$) satisfying the following conditions:

1. $\emptyset\notin F$;
2. for all $A,B\in P(X)$, if $A\in F$ and $B\in F$, then $A\cap B\in F$;
3. for all $A,B\in P(X)$, if $A\in F$ and $A\subseteq B$, then $B\in F$.

Sometimes the first condition is omitted, but then $F$ is obviously the whole of $P(X)$, due to the final condition and $P(X)$ is called the “improper filter”.

Since $F$ is not empty, there is $A\in F$. Since $A\subseteq X$, the third condition implies $X\in F$.

If a filter contains a finite set, then it contains a finite set $A_0$ with minimal number of elements. Suppose $B\in F$. Then $B\cap A_0$ is finite and is a subset of $A_0$, so $B\cap A_0=A_0$ by minimality. Hence $A_0\subseteq B$ and therefore
$$
F=\{B\in P(X):A_0\subseteq B\}
$$

Comment: If $X$ has a topology, we also have the notions of filter of zero-sets, or filter of closed sets or, filter of open sets which essentially the same axioms except that all members are of the mentioned type only, so that 3 only applies to sets of the same type that are supersets. For the answer it doesn't matter as $X$ is in all mentioned classes anyway. But filters on other lattices do occur too. They can be useful tools as well.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma One could write a book about filters… On the other hand finite filters are quite dull.

Comment: Yes, filters of finite sets are rarely considered. They have no topological usefulness that I'm aware of.

Comment: This presentation of the definition makes the "nonempty" condition seem perhaps artificial.  A more natural version would be to require that $F$ is closed under all _finite_ intersections, rather than just binary intersections.  This then implies that $X\in F$ as the nullary intersection.